# How to add filter on google sheets using google sheets api

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

first of all sorry my bad eng
I'm create pivot table using google sheet api and i did it but i do not know how to add filter on it here is my code

```
pivotTable.FilterSpecs = append(pivotTable.FilterSpecs, &sheets.PivotFilterSpec{
        //ColumnOffsetIndex: 0,
        DataSourceColumnReference: &sheets.DataSourceColumnReference{Name: "yil"},
        FilterCriteria: &sheets.PivotFilterCriteria{
            VisibleValues:    []string{"yil"},
            VisibleByDefault: true,
        },
    })
```

alwasy two error comes

1. Invalid requests[0].updateCells: 'data_source_column_reference' is only applicable for data source pivot table. Please use 'column_offset_index'., badRequest
   or
2. googleapi: Error 400: Invalid requests[0].updateCells: At least one pivot filter spec source must be specified., badRequest

please help me thank you